# xml schema constraints integer increment

Tags: xml, xsd, integer, constraints, schema

I want to write an XML Schema with an constraint for intgegers. The interger should only be valid with a certain increment.

The basic element could be something like this:

```
 <xs:element name="MotorFrequency">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                <xs:maxInclusive value="2000000" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

I need a constraint that only allows an interger with an 4000 increment, like 4000, 8000, 12000 etc.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only with XSD **1.1**, you could use an `<xs:assertion>`:

```
<xs:element name="MotorFrequency">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
            <xs:maxInclusive value="2000000" />
            <xs:assertion test="($value mod 4000) = 0"></xs:assertion>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

That way, an error will be raised if assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with XSD 1.0, then you could write a regular expression

```
value="[0-9]*(([02468][048])|([13579][26])000"
```

Not tested.